# iOS where should the cleaning code of a custom `UIView` go?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` and I would like to do something like unregister itself from receiving notifications and other cleaning up stuff, so where should I put the cleaning code?

Comment: `didReceiveMemoryWarning` for dealing with memory issues and `dealloc` for activities that need to be "undone" before the `UIView` is deallocated.

Comment: @RoboticCat Thanks, that's helpful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put it in `dealloc`.

```
-(void)dealloc {

    // tear down here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put cleaning up code in `- dealloc`